# How to create DNS catch-all entry (wildcard) in Windows 2008 R2?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2

How to create entry in DNS to catch-all queries (wildcard)? For example `domain.local` with IP 192.168.1.1 and any subdomain to that will respond with same ip (bbbaasa.domain.local, aaa.domain.local - 192.168.1.1)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create an A record of `*` within the forward lookup zone for `domain.local` pointing to `192.168.1.1`.

Comment: I did that.. i have project.domain.local .. i have created `directory` sub1 and under it I have (same as parent folder) Type Host (A) Data 192.168.1.1. Additionally I have created * A record pointing to 192.168.1.1 and having sub1.project.domain.local works .. but aaa.sub1.project.domain.local doesn't.

Comment: It works now. Must have been `waiting time`.