# Create subdomains in windows 2008 R2

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2

How do I create and make subdomains like aaa.domainname.com and bbb.domainname.com?

I want them to redirect to one url. I found similar question [Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/314810/how-to-create-dns-catch-all-entry-wildcard-in-windows-2008-r2). Can anyone explain the steps how to achieve this. Thanks in advance it will be very help full.

Comment: Do you want actual windows active directory domains or just want to set it up in DNS? And are you looking to have these as just hostnames or actual domains?

Comment: Note that if it is sub-domains in the Active Directory sense, Microsoft does not recommend this anymore. They now recommend the single-forest single-domain topology.

Comment: @Rex whichever way it's possible.. AS dSebastien told us that Microsoft doesn't recommend Active directory domains... And sorry if I sound stupid because I am a newbie...

Comment: @dSebastien Thanks for tell me..I didn't know that...

Comment: @dSebastien Could you cite a Technet article or similar that states that Microsoft don't recommend creating child domains? I've not come across this before and I'd be interested to know what their reasoning is.

Comment: Now don't this as "you should never ever have multiple domains/forests", that's not what I'm saying, just that their message is that if it does everything you need, then single-forest single-domain is the easiest to administer: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737091(v=ws.10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-reading your question: when you say redirect, are you saying you want to have something setup so that when someone points a browser to abc.domainname.com they get sent to www.domainname.com?

If so, you don't need subdomains to do that. You could just setup CNAME records that resolve to the name you want it to go to.